# How to change URL inside CSS?

Tags: html, css

i would like to change the url inside my css, point to a file inside my system.
ie,

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

i want to change src to like this

```
 src: url(web/font/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You may be able to use LESS to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at relative pathing http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

You basically will have to point to your file using a relative path not an absolute path/link.

Comment: @pale-green-color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @pale-green-color;
} like this? @ STEVE MATHEWS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't you answered your own question here?
Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

```
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```